# What's the proper term for a "scale-equivariant" function

Tags: functions, equivalence-relations

What do math people call a function with the property:
$$
s\cdot f(x) = f(s\cdot x)
$$
Where s is some scalar?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function

Comment: This is the answer!  Thanks.  If you post it as "answer" I'll mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As responder Nick Liu said, it is a

## [Homogeneous Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_function)